# How to render to a page A, data that are being posted through a form from page B using Node-express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, templating-engine

**The problem**

Hi people. I have been strangling for the past half an hour trying to solve the rending method. The problem is that I keep getting a specific ERROR  'Cannot get a specific URL' when I post data through a form from Page A and want to render these data in Page B. Although i am using POST i keep getting the data in the URL.

[image: Image 1/3]
[image: Image 2/3]
[image: Image 3/3]

```
 // Import core packages
    const express = require( "express" );
    const path = require( "path" );
    const bodyParser = require( "body-parser" );

    // Declare global constants
    const app = express();
    const users = [];

    // Register a template engine
    app.set( "view engine" , "ejs" );
    app.set( "views" , "templates" );

    // Middleware

    app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded( {
        extended : false
    } ) );

    app.get( "/" , ( req , res , next ) => {

        res.render( "index" , { pageTitle : "Home Page" } );

    } );

    app.get( "/users" , ( req , res , next ) => {

        res.render( "users" , { pageTitle : "Users Page" , users } );

    } );

    app.post( "/add-user" , ( req , res , next )=> {

        users.push( { username : req.body.username } );
        res.redirect( "/users" );

    } );

    // Server listening
    app.listen( 3000 );
```

**users.js**
[image: users.ejs]
**index.js**
[image: index.js]

**UPDATED**

The problem was in the form structure.

It should be `method="POST"` instead of `type="POST"`.

Comment: Instead of redirecting, why not render the target page in your `add-user` post?

Comment: I know this isn't an answer to the question but you don't need bodyParser nowadays. You can use `app.use(express.json());`

Answer (score 1):

Use method get and take req.query.username.
Try like this:

```
app.get( "/add-user" , ( req , res , next )=> {

    users.push( { username : req.query.username } );
    res.redirect( "/users" );

} );
```

Comment: it will not do the trick. I tried your way by inspecting the network tab and the query result to a get response which is not ideal for pushing data into a database through a form. So it does not help in this scenario.